# React Form reload page after adding Style

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form

I am using "*react-final-form*" script for Forms (I have also tried with "*react-hook-form*") and if I add style to my Inputs then onSubmit doesnt work (it reloads whole page).

I can not figure it out why.

There is snippet with part of my code -> https://codesandbox.io/embed/boring-wind-gnqx5?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

If I delete -> **FormContainerPart** <- Container in App-js then it works.

Thank you for helping!

Comment: Forms in general load a new page when submitted. When target is provided, forms reload the page (but send the form data to the server in the GET or POST request. The onSubmit function does not prevent this. If you want the button to not actually submit the http request, you have to return false from the onSubmit function. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8664680/10875738

Comment: Also, I got this in the sandbox: `Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <form> cannot appear as a descendant of <form>.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not about styling, but about your generated HTML structure.
`FormContainerPart` is a `form` so when you're submitting your form (by clicking the button) you're submitting your `Form` from `react-final-form` **AND** your `form` from `FormContainerPart`.

And as you're not catching the `onSubmit` handler on your `form` by `FormContainerPart`, well it goes to default navigator behavior, which is: reload the page

So, as there is no need for `FormContainerPart` to be a `form` just change your `styled` to

```js
export const FormContainerPart = styled.div`
...
`
```

Comment: Thx man... I did not notice that .form in style! Cheers!